# Why is a theme needed if page builder is there in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new into the arena of WordPress. I started learning about how to create website  using WordPress. I am wondering if a page layout can be fully designed and customized by using a page builder, why i need to use a theme. Isn't theme is used to define how my contents are going to be shown in pages ?

Answer (score 0):

A theme is actually a collection of files that control the way the site is displayed and to some degree how it behaves. While page builders typically allow you control of some aspects of the visual interface, you cannot have a Wordpress site without an active theme.